# Open mdb app using Openoffice 4.0.1

Tags: ms-access, openoffice-base

I have an mdb access application that I want to open using openoffice 4.0.1 so how to do it? is it possible?

Comment: http://www.openoffice.org/FAQs/ms-access/ms-access.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link below your question shows, it will be possible to get data out of the mdb but as far as running reports and forms, you will need to use Access.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For opening and getting data no problem but for running a form (this is my case) only Access can be used to work.